# SignalR: Throwing HubException on server and getting the error message on typescript client

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

Starting the connection client-side:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._gameKey = parseInt(this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('game-key'));

    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                          .withUrl('http://localhost:5000/match').build();

    this._hubConnection.on('Connected', (data) => {this.connected(data)});

    ...

    this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here is the back-end method I'm invoking:

```
public async Task SendResources(string gameKey) {
      throw new HubException("oops");
      ...
}
```

In my typescript client I have:

```
public connected(data): void {    
  this._hubConnection.invoke('SendResources', this._gameKey).catch(this.errorHandler);
}

public errorHandler(err): void {
  console.log(err);
}
```

The execution flow enters 'errorHandler' with 'err' being of type Error. The problem is that I can't access the message of the exception. All info I get from the 'err' variable is this:

[image]

Any Idea how to handle error messages correctly with signalR?

### Versions:

.net core: 2.1
angular: 5
@aspnet/signalr: 1.0.0

Comment: Show where you start the connection. Best show all signalr relevant javascript.Whats inside "this._gameKey"?

Comment: @Stephu I've edited in the connection building code. this._gameKey is just an int.

Comment: Your shure that the connectipn established?

Comment: @Stephu yes. It is.

Comment: Open issue: [aspnet/SignalR#2439](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2439)

Comment: Have you tried enabling detailed error on the server side (e.g. like this: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/3d0f68b22c05b918c4e2637af0d879e34c0b48a2/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Tests/HubConnectionHandlerTests.cs#L515)?